# Java Anonymous Class with Interface

Tags: java, class, interface, anonymous

I didn't write Java for a long time and need some help with something (maybe) simple.

So I got this `Class` in which an `Interface` is declared :

```
public class test(){
   
interface Checker(){
 public check();
}

public someFunction(List param1, Checker param2){
   //[do something here]
}
...


public static void main (...){

   someFunction(List param1, new Checker(){
          ...
          //[implementation of interface]
          ...
      });
 }
```

So my problem is, that (and the actual Code works fine)

1. I really don't get **why** the method `someFunction();` expects a `Interface` as a parameter
2. I also don't understand **why** I can pass an instance of an interface to that function`(in`main()`). The second argument that I'm passing the` someFunction();`, is an instance of an interface, right?
   Well, what i was thinking of, is that it actually is some kind of anonymous class and therefore it might be possible.

But as I said, it's been a while since I wrote java code, and I didn't find an answer yet, so I would be really grateful if somebody could explain to me why and how this piece of code is working.

Comment: This won't compile. `check` lacks a returntype.

Comment: 1. because it was written that way. 2.  yes, this is anonymous class.

Comment: Implementing against Interfaces is a common practice against tight coupling. someFunction doesn't care *how* you "check". You could make the behavior of `someFunction` configurable by injecting different implementations of a Checker. Look at sorting: By injecting a Comparator you can turn around the sorting order.

Comment: *"somebody could explain me why and how this poiece of code is working"* --- thats easy : **it isnt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume public check() was a typo.

> 1. i really dont get, WHY the method someFunction() expects a Interface as parameter

Why not? Your interface is `Checker` and your method signature is

```
public someFunction(List param1, Checker param2)
```

The second argument takes a `Checker`.

> 2. i also dont understand WHY i can pass an instance of an interface to that function (in main()).

You aren't passing an instance of an interface. You are passing an anonymous class. When you say:

```
new Checker(){
          ...
          //[implementation of interface]
          ...
      });
```

you are implementing the interface.

Comment: So, is that some sort of short spell for a anonymous class that implements an interface?  Instead of --> new nameOfAnonymousClass implements Checker, you can just write new Checker() ?

Comment: btw. the "public check();" wasn'T a typo, but a sample function of that interface (that isn't implemented due to the fact, that it belongs to that interface)

Comment: Yes. When you say `new SomeInterface(){/**implementation**/} ` that's an anonymous class. If you say `new SomeClass implements SomeInterface(){}` that would no longer be anonymous, would it? It would now be a `SomeClass` I don't believe that syntax to be valid anyway.

Comment: @Malte2323 There is a typo: you forgot the return type.

Answer (score 1):

1) Because by definition `public someFunction(List param1, Checker param2)` expects an object of Checker (see parameter 2)
2) Yes, it is an anonymous class, and an instance of it `new Checker()` creates an object of the class which is passed.

Hence, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. i really dont get, WHY the method someFunction() expects a Interface as parameter

That's a choice of the developer but using an interface here allows you to use any implementation - and only interfaces allow a sort of muliple inheritance in Java.

> 2. i also dont understand WHY i can pass an instance of an interface to that function (in main()). The second argument that i'm passing the someFunction(), is an instance of an interface, right? Well, what i was thinking of, is that it actually is some kind of anonymous Class and therefore it might be possible.

The code you see basically creates an anonymous implementation of the interface and instance of that anonymous class. So your guess is correct here.